Kong 502 Bad Gateway
I have two VMs. One is running an Apache server with a Django API and the other is running Kong. The two VMs are on the same network and can ping each other, and I can access the Django site on my browser from my Kong VM.
I have configured the Kong route to point specifically to the local IP address on the network (192.168.x.x) instead of localhost. On the Kong VM I can do curl requests directly to the API just fine, and I can access the site on my browser, and the test route to httpbin works fine as well. But I still continue to run into this error when I try to access the API through my service.
I'm running Kong as is, no docker stuff
I tried getting the logs and got no information other than the Bad Gateway stuff, I've triple checked and verified that the routes are pointing to the correct local IP address and route and not localhost, still nothing
I also have a web application firewall setup (Modsecurity) but disabling the firewall doesn't fix the problem and no relevant error logs show up that might suggest the firewall is blocking my requests
My route is at 192.168.226.128/api/mymodels and my services are configured as below
{
  "data": [
    {
      "updated_at": 1715195774,
      "path": "/api/mymodels/",
      "name": "main",
      "retries": 5,
      "ca_certificates": null,
      "port": 80,
      "client_certificate": null,
      "protocol": "http",
      "enabled": true,
      "connect_timeout": 60000,
      "created_at": 1715180691,
      "read_timeout": 60000,
      "tls_verify": null,
      "tags": null,
      "tls_verify_depth": null,
      "write_timeout": 60000,
      "host": "192.168.228.128",
      "id": "0052c1db-e28d-47ac-9ad4-5d41c510f066"
    },
  ],
  "next": null
}   

{
      "updated_at": 1715181353,
      "snis": null,
      "name": null,
      "tags": [],
      "preserve_host": false,
      "destinations": null,
      "methods": null,
      "strip_path": true,
      "hosts": null,
      "created_at": 1715180717,
      "request_buffering": true,
      "response_buffering": true,
      "sources": null,
      "https_redirect_status_code": 426,
      "regex_priority": 0,
      "service": {
        "id": "0052c1db-e28d-47ac-9ad4-5d41c510f066"
      },
      "protocols": [
        "http",
        "https"
      ],
      "paths": [
        "/main"
      ],
      "headers": null,
      "path_handling": "v0",
      "id": "dd3d9f8e-4e88-44e5-afb1-3414e7c1b84d"
    } 

Any advice would be appreciated thank you

fixed it by setting a domain name in /etc/hosts, for some reason this works. unsure why
but go to /etc/hosts, add a line that maps your target upstream's local IP address to some random domain name of your choice, then change the Kong service to serve that domain name instead of your local IP.
192.168.226.128   mydomain.ccc

then go to your service and change it as follows
"host": "mydomain.ccc",
what a waste of 4 hours
